# Полтергейст при рендеренге гуглботом страницы на Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular2

Какие-то абсолютно непостижимые уму вещи происходят при рендеринге страницы Angular 4 гуглботом.

Недавно наткнулся на один интересный эксперимент https://goralewicz.com/blog/javascript-seo-experiment/
Вкратце, эксериментально доказано что гуглбот успешно исполняет любой javascript на сайте за исключением Angular 2.
Вот пример из эксперимента http://jsseo.expert/angular2/
А вот его github https://github.com/kamilgrymuza/jsseo/tree/master/angular2

Недавно начал осваивать Angular 4 и решил проверить действительно ли это работает на данный момент, а также возможно ли спрятать от гуглбота баннер на сайте.
Перенёс пример к себе на сервер http://unni.us/40.html, проверил в google webmaster tools - "Fetch as Google" - все работает как и в эксперимете выше:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот файлы этого проекта на моем сервере:

- http://unni.us/app/main.ts
- http://unni.us/app/app.module.ts
- http://unni.us/app/app.component.ts

---

Окей, все работает, гуглбот не видит подгружаемый текст - набросаю пример чуть сложнее htt​p:/​/un​ni.​us/​51.​htm​l
Он тоже работает, но когда я иду в google webmaster tools - "Fetch as Google" и кликаю на результаты рендеринга страницы гуглботом - ЧУДЕСА, гуглбот исполняет весь код Angular 4 и выводит полностью отрендеренную страницу!!! Как такое может быть???
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я все делал, как в первом примере! Даже файлы systemjs.config.js и systemjs-angular-loader.js оба примера используют одинаковые.
Вот файлы этого проекта на моем сервере:

- http://unni.us/app2/main.ts
- http://unni.us/app2/app.module.ts
- http://unni.us/app2/app.component.ts
- http://unni.us/app2/btn.component.ts

Сама библиотека Angular 4 подгружается с unpkg.com
Может кто-то поможет разобраться как такое может быть, проверял и рендерил десятки раз - первый пример гуглбот НЕ исполняет и подгружаемый ангуляром текст НЕ видит. Второй точно такой же пример исполняет и подгружаемые элементы видит. ПОЧЕМУ???